# Tree is not displayed propery in DOJO

Tags: javascript, dojo, digit

I am new to DOJO 1.6

I trying to display tree with sub folders.

```
dojo.require("dojo.data.ItemFileWriteStore");
            dojo.require("dijit.form.Button");
            dojo.require("dijit.tree.TreeStoreModel");
dojo.require("dojo.store.Memory");
dojo.require("dijit.Tree");
            dojo.addOnLoad(function() {
                 // Create test store, adding the getChildren() method required by ObjectStoreModel
        var data =  [ { id: 1, name: "answerTypeLabel",                 type:'scenario',    children:[{_reference: 2}]},
                       { id: 2, name: "acceptRequestLabel",             type:'paragraph',   data: "acceptRequestLabel"},
                       { id: 3, name: "rejectRequestLabel",             type:'scenario',    children:[{_reference: 5},{_reference: 6}]},
                       { id: 4, name: "MoreInformationLabel",       type:'scenario',    children:[{_reference: 7},{_reference: 8}]},
                       { id: 5, name: "rejectRequestStatusLabel",   type:'paragraph',   data: "rejectRequestStatusLabel"},
                       { id: 6, name: "rejectRequestNotCoveredLabel", type:'paragraph',     data: "rejectRequestNotCoveredLabel" },
                       { id: 7, name: "MoreInformationDocumentLabel", type:'paragraph',     data: "MoreInformationDocumentLabel"},
                       { id: 8, name: "MoreInformationDataLabel",   type:'paragraph',   data: "MoreInformationDataLabel"}
                     ];
         // Building the store object
        var sortableStore = new dojo.data.ItemFileWriteStore({
                    data: {
                        identifier: 'id',
                        label: 'name',
                        items: data 
                    },
                    });
        // building the model           
        var model = new dijit.tree.ForestStoreModel({

                    store: sortableStore, 
            query: { 
                id: "*" 
            }, 
            rootId: "root", 
            rootLabel: "sorting of tree"

        }); 
        // Building the tree            
        var tree = new dijit.Tree({

            model:model,
            'class': "tundra" 
        },
        "resourceTree");

            });
```

[image: output of code].

Here Id 2 in a child of Id 1 , so while displaying Id 2 must be inside Id 1.
But here Id 2 appears inside id 1 and also on the same level of id 1.(There is a duplication of all the all the child ids ).
This is case with id 2,5,6,7,8.

I want to remove the duplication.

Ouptput should be like

[image: correctoutput should be like this]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reason is that you apply a non-hierachial store onto a tree which is not supposed to display items that has parents as a sibling to the root.

To 'fix' this, the referenced id's needs **to not get matched** by the `model query`.

In your case of data, it looks like the `type:'paragraph'` is supposed to be leaves. Therefore set the query to match `type:'scenario'` as opposed to your current ' id: "*" '

```
    var model = new dijit.tree.ForestStoreModel({

                store: sortableStore, 
        query: { 
            type:'scenario'
        }, 
        rootId: "root", 
        rootLabel: "sorting of tree"

    });
```

Comment: oh yes.. my Bad.. Thanks :) Now have to sort this using http://jsfiddle.net/AnxBW/

Comment: You should sort the store serverside imo